# UPDATE a column value using JOIN and multiple WHERE conditions in PySpark

Tags: sql, join, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, sql-update

I have a SQL query which I am trying to transform into PySpark which have some `join`s and multiple `where` conditions:

```sql
UPDATE COMPANY1
INNER JOIN COMPANY2
ON COMPANY1.C1_PROFIT = COMPANY2.C2_PROFIT 
SET COMPANY2.C2_TARGET = "1"
WHERE (((COMPANY2.C2_TARGET) Is Null)
  AND ((COMPANY1.C1_SALES) Is Null)
  AND ((COMPANY2.C2_PROFIT) Is Not Null));
```

PySpark query I am trying to execute (`df_1`->`COMPANY2` & `df_2`->`Company1`):

```py
join = ((df_1.C2_PROFIT == df_2.C1_PROFIT) & \
  (df_1.C2_TARGET=='') & \
  (df_2.C1_SALES=='') & \
  (df_1.C2_PROFIT!=''))
df_1 = (df_1.alias('a')
  .join(df_2.alias('b'), join, 'left')
  .select(
    *[c for c in df_1.columns if c != 'C2_TARGET'],
    F.expr("nvl2(b.C1_PROFIT, '1', a.C2_TARGET) C2_TARGET")
  )
)
```

But I am still getting `null` values in column "C2_TARGET".

For the information: column "C1_Profit" is null-free, but in "C2_Profit" we sometimes have `null` as well as values.

Example inputs:

```
+------------------+--------------+
|  C1_PROFIT       |C1_SALES      |
+------------------+--------------+
|5637              |     Positive |
|7464              |              |
|43645             |              |
|64657             |      Growth P|
+------------------+--------------+

+------------------+--------------+
|  C2_PROFIT       |C2_TARGET     |
+------------------+--------------+
|                  |              |
|7464              |              |
|43645             |              |
|64657             |              |
+------------------+--------------+
```

Expected result:

[image]

```
join_on = (df_1.C1_PROFIT == df_2.C2_PROFIT) & \   --JOIN CONDITION
            (df_1.C1_REVENUE == df_3.C3_REVENUE_BREAK) & \  --JOIN CONDITION
            (df_1.C1_LOSS == df_4.C4_TOTAL_LOSS) & \        --JOIN CONDITION
            ((df_4.MARGIN_OF_COMPANY) > (df_3.LAST_YEAR_MARGIN))   --WHERE CONDITION
df = (df_1.alias('a')
    .join(df_2.alias('b'), join_on, 'left')
    .join(df_3.alias('c'), join_on, 'left')
    .join(df_4.alias('c'), join_on. 'left')
    .select(
    *[c for c in df_2.columns if c != 'C2_TARGET'],
    F.expr("nvl2(b.C2_PROFIT, '1', a.C2_TARGET) C2_TARGET")
```

Comment: `(df_1.C2_PROFIT == df_1.C1_PROFIT)` -- should this be `df_2.C1_PROFIT` ?

Comment: hi @samkart, do you need any additional info?

Comment: can you please share a few sample rows for us to test?

Comment: i have added some examples can you please check once

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74144537/how-to-do-joins-and-update-together-in-a-same-query-in-pyspark/74145713?noredirect=1#comment131346329_74145713), you have an example of how to do

```sql
UPDATE A INNER JOIN B
...
SET A...
```

In your case, you `SET B...`:

```sql
UPDATE A INNER JOIN B
...
SET B...
```

*You have correctly switched the order of your dataframes.*

What's not correct is that `''` is not the same as `null`. You must use `.isNull()` and `.isNotNull()` in your conditions.

---

Example inputs:

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
df_1 = spark.createDataFrame(
    [(5637, 'Positive'),
     (7464, None),
     (43645, None),
     (64657, 'Growth P')],
    ['C1_PROFIT', 'C1_SALES'])

df_2 = spark.createDataFrame(
    [(None, None),
     (7464, None),
     (43645, None),
     (64657, None)],
    'C2_PROFIT int, C2_TARGET string')
```

Script:

```py
join_on = (df_1.C1_PROFIT == df_2.C2_PROFIT) & \
          df_2.C2_TARGET.isNull() & \
          df_1.C1_SALES.isNull() & \
          df_2.C2_PROFIT.isNotNull()
df = (df_2.alias('a')
    .join(df_1.alias('b'), join_on, 'left')
    .select(
        *[c for c in df_2.columns if c != 'C2_TARGET'],
        F.expr("nvl2(b.C1_PROFIT, '1', a.C2_TARGET) C2_TARGET")
    )
)

df.show()
# +---------+---------+
# |C2_PROFIT|C2_TARGET|
# +---------+---------+
# |     null|     null|
# |     7464|        1|
# |    64657|     null|
# |    43645|        1|
# +---------+---------+
```